# How can i build an ubuntu touch app only in c++ (without qml) and with cmake

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, qt, cmake

is there a way to configure a cmake file for building a click-package without qml.
i like to start programming in the main function with QApplication and only my own window class.

my goal is to write a game with open gl(es2).
at the moment i'm using a custom QQuickItem, which is connected to QQuickWindow's afterRenderering signal and included in my Main.qml

it works, but i don't need qml and i'm happier without it and the use of qt's scenegraph has limitations like 'leaving the GL context in the same state as it was when the signal handler was entered'